# UI doesn't update after executing ReactiveCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, reactiveui

All I want is to get some data from the service and then show it with a DataGrid in a new window after button click. First of all I should mention that loading the data have to place in a new window not in its owner.

The problem is any approach dealing with a time consuming task via ReactiveCommands (either CreateFromTask or CreateFromObservable) brings no result for me. I get my data from the service successfully, then Data property updates successfully too BUT I see completely nothing but the names of DataGrid columns. If I replace LoadDataCommand with just `Data = new List<...>() { new ..., new...}` (hardcoded) everything works fine hence the trouble is in loading the data and giving this data to UI not in binding as I used to think.

Unfortunatelly I'm quite a beginner with ReactiveUI and I've read some articles in reactiveui.net/docs and answers of other here before ask but any of them doesn't help me even though it seems like I apply same approaches.

**Owner:**

```
var window = new PaymentsDetailingView(request)
            {
                WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen
            };
            window.ShowDialog();
```

Then I start loading data in the constructor like this:

**xaml.cs**

```
public PaymentsDetailingView(CounterpartyPaymentRequest request)
        {
            ViewModel = new PaymentsDetailingViewModel(request);
            InitializeComponent();

            this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
            { // some bindings (to DataGrid too)

                this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ViewModel.LoadDataCommand).SelectMany(x => x.Execute()).Subscribe()
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
            });
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public List<PaymentsDetailingData> Data
        {
            get => _data;
            set =>  this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _data, value);
        }       

        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, List<PaymentDetailingResponseModel>> LoadDataCommand { get; set; } 
        
        public PaymentsDetailingViewModel(CounterpartyPaymentRequest request)
        {
            Request = request;

            //LoadDataCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(GetAndShowPaymentDetailedDataAsync);

            LoadDataCommand =
                ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(() => Observable.StartAsync(GetAndShowPaymentDetailedDataAsync, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler));

                //LoadDataCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
                //  () =>
                //      Observable.FromAsync(GetAndShowPaymentDetailedDataAsync));

            LoadDataCommand/*.ObserveOn(RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)*/
                .Subscribe(x => Data = x.AddTotalRow().ToUiModels());

            LoadDataCommand.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(e => this.Log().Error(e));
            LoadDataCommand.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsLoading, out _isLoading);
        }       

        private async Task<List<PaymentDetailingResponseModel>> GetAndShowPaymentDetailedDataAsync()
        { 
            var arService = Locator.Current.GetService<IAnalyticalReportingService>();
            var results = await arService.ExecuteDetailedCounterpartyPaymentInfo(Request, new CancellationToken());

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probably first worth checking that the bindings on the view side are `OneWay`, e.g. `{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}`. Such platforms as UWP and some WPF controls tend to use `OneTime` bindings by default. This isn't applicable to ReactiveUI type-safe bindings, though.

Also worth adding `.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)` (not `TaskPoolScheduler`) right before a call to `.Subscribe` on the `LoadDataCommand`. `.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)` ensures that the code inside `Subscribe` is executed on the main thread.

Comment: If none of these helps, probably worth making a minimal repro and heading over to [ReactiveUI Slack](http://reactiveui.net/slack) (the `reactiveui` support channel).